# Circular Permutation with restrictions and repetitions

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I have 4 different types of objects, each of which could appear more than once based on the input. (Would be further clarified with examples below)

The 4 objects are, "A", "B", "C", "D"

These objects are to be arranged in a circular manner such that no 2 similar objects should be adjacent to one another. Further more, one of the position is deemed as a "crown" position, meaning, that particular position can be distinguished.

Given any input, could we formulate the answer?

**Example 1**

If the input is ABAB, this could be arranged in 2 ways **circularly**.
(The part in bold is the crown position)

**A**BAB, **B**ABA

**Example 2**

If the input is ABABA, this could be arranged in 0 ways **circularly** as 2 similar objects would be next to each other.

**Example 3**

If the input is ABC, this could be arranged in 6 ways **circularly**.
(The part in bold is the crown position)

**A**BC. **A**CB, **B**AC, **B**CA, **C**AB, **C**BA

**Example 4**

If the input is ABCA, this could be arranged in 4 ways **circularly**.
(The part in bold is the crown position)

**A**BAC, **A**CAB, **B**ACA, **C**ABA

My question is, is there a formula that i could easily use to compute this? I need to program this in a computer so if I could have a formula it would be easy by simply counting the number of identical objects and plucking it into the formula.

Comment: The only way I know how to do this is with generating functions. You can modify the generating function for Carlitz words to yield circular Carlitz words. However it's not particularly pretty so I'm not sure whether it would fulfil your criteria of a formula that is "easy to compute".